# Why is java mail api throws exceptions?

Tags: java, api, email

The task: need to send a mail to user.
Lib: java mail api 1.6.2

Code of program:

```
    final String username = "ns**t@gmail.com";
         final String password = "x9G";
         final String to = "to@hhh.bla";
         final String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
         final String from ="ns@gmail.com";
         
         Properties props = new Properties();
         props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
         props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
         props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
         props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
         
         Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                  new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                     protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                     }
                  });
         
         try {
             // Create a default MimeMessage object.
             Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    
             // Set From: header field of the header.
             message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    
             // Set To: header field of the header.
             message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
             InternetAddress.parse(to));
    
             // Set Subject: header field
             message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
    
             // Now set the actual message
             message.setText("Hello, this is sample for to check send "
                + "email using JavaMailAPI ");
    
             // Send message
             Transport.send(message);
    
             System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
    
          } catch (MessagingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
          }
```

But, this throws exception:

```
> **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at ExcelID.ExcelArtifact.App.main(App.java:174)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2209)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:740)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at ExcelID.ExcelArtifact.App.main(App.java:169)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:359)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:238)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2175)
    ... 7 more
**
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the port to 465

```
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
```

Answer (score 1):

> Exception : java.net.ConnectException

This means your request didn't getting response from server in stipulated time. And their are some reasons for this exception:

- Too many requests overloading the server
- Request packet loss because of wrong network configuration or line
  overload
- Sometimes firewall consume request packet before sever getting
- Also depends on thread connection pool configuration and current
  status of connection pool
- Response packet lost during transition
- The IP/domain or port is incorrect.   The IP/domain or port (i.e
  service) is down
- The IP/domain is taking longer than your default timeout to respond.
- You have a firewall that is blocking requests or responses on
  whatever port you are using
- You have a firewall that is blocking requests to that particular
  host.
- you are not connected to internet.